# HTML Android Video - get metadata in same request as video fetch?

Tags: android, html, video, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

On video play for Android 4.4+, multiple network requests are made. On 4.4 it seems that one of these requests is for metadata, and stops around 2.5 megabytes. For 5.0.2, I see two full requests being fulfilled

I'm curious if anyone knows a way to only make one network request

Currently I'm using [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) and Little Snitch to confirm:

Hold Android Wifi --> Hold WiFi Name --> Advanced --> Proxy --> Enter IP from `ifconfig | grep bro | awk '/inet/ {print $2}'` --> Set Port to 8888 --> Start Charles --> Go to a video in the Android Chrome browser

I'm surprised that other people aren't complaining about this

Also very surprised that Chrome recognizes "autostart" rather than "autoplay"

Google driving me nuts.............

Full video is 5.5 megabytes, in this example Android 5.0.2 is doing two full fetches, one using partials, one as a standalone stream, totalling 9.9 megabytes for no reason

[image: using http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated browser requests are quite a common problem and it appears there may be multiple causes, but amongst the most common are empty attributes in the HTML itself - for example:

- empty url attribute in CSS tag
- empty src attribute in img or video tag
- empty href attribute

See some discussion here for example: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64810